# Why do these ways of creating a reference behave differently?

Tags: rust

The following code runs correctly.

```
{
    let a = &mut 3;
    *a = 4;
    assert_eq!(*a, 4);
}
```

The following runs also.

```
{
    let a = Some(&3);
    let mut b = a.unwrap();
    assert_eq!(a.unwrap(), &3);
}
```

But the following can't be compiled.

```
{
    let a = Some(&mut 3);
    assert_eq!(*a.unwrap(), 3);
}
```

The error is:

```
40 |         let a = Some(&mut 3);
   |                           ^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                           |
   |                           creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
41 |         assert_eq!(*a.unwrap(), 3);
   |                     - borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Why Rust compiler treats those references differently that the first two pieces of code can make reference's lives more than temporary while the last one can't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a concept in Rust called [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension).  There are rules that govern when a temporary's lifetime is extended, though.  It doesn't happen any time a borrow of a temporary occurs; the expression on the right side of a `let` statement needs to be a so-called "extending expression."  This part of the document linked above neatly explains the first and third examples in your question:

> So the borrow expressions in `&mut 0`, `(&1, &mut 2)`, and `Some { 0: &mut 3 }` are all extending expressions. The borrows in `&0 + &1` and `Some(&mut 0)` are not: the latter is syntactically a function call expression.

Since the expression assigned to `a` in the third example isn't an extending expression, the lifetime of the temporary is not extended beyond the let statement, and that causes the lifetime problem.

Why does this work for `Some(&3)` then?  Because of [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion):

> Promotion of a value expression to a `'static` slot occurs when the expression could be written in a constant and borrowed, and that borrow could be dereferenced where the expression was originally written, without changing the runtime behavior.

Since you borrow immutably, Rust allocates a hidden, static `i32` and borrows that instead, giving you an `Option<&'static i32>`, which is obviously valid for the whole life of the program itself.  This is not technically temporary lifetime extension because after the `i32` is promoted to have static lifetime it's no longer a temporary.

It's basically equivalent to this (except that `HIDDEN` has no name):

```
static HIDDEN: i32 = 3;
let a = Some(&HIDDEN);
let mut b = a.unwrap();
assert_eq!(a.unwrap(), &HIDDEN);
```