# Return reference to variable created in block

Tags: rust

This code doesn't compile:

```
let y = {
    let x = "foo".to_owned();
    &x
};
dbg!(y);
```

But this code does:

```
let y = {
    let x = "foo".to_owned();
    &x.clone()
};
dbg!(y);
```

I thought we were not able to return reference to local variables, but in this case we can. `x.clone()` is created inside the block, but we can get a reference to it outside the block. Yet we are not able to do the same on `x`. What is happening here?

Comment: @Enethecommentflagger This is not related, there is static promotion and here is temporary lifetime extension.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Then [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719617/why-do-these-ways-of-creating-a-reference-behave-differently/71719720#71719720) would have done the trick. But now that the question was reopened, I cannot edit them in.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I hesitate to close this as duplicate of them as they don't clearly talk about the difference between the two snippets, and this is what this question asks.

Comment: My understanding of Rust is limited, but I don't see the second code returning  reference to a local variable. It returns a reference to a new value *intialized from* the value of `x`, not a reference to `x` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for temporary lifetime extension are a little complex, but the difference in the 2 code snippets in this question boils down to this:

**Only values created in the final expression of the block will have lifetime extension applied.**

- In the case of the 2nd block (which compiles), the return value of `clone()` has its lifetime extended because it was created in the final expression of the block.
- On the other hand, in the 1st block (which fails to compile), the final expression of the initializer block is a reference to a variable created in a previous statement. This means *temporary lifetime extension* is not applied. In fact, when you look at it this way, it makes sense, since `x` is not a *temporary*, but an actual named variable.

It's explained in the Rust reference this way:

> For a let statement with an initializer, an extending expression is an expression which is ... The final expression of any extending block expression.
> ...
> The operand of any extending borrow expression has its temporary scope extended.
>
> -- [Rust Reference sec 10.8, Temporary Lifetime Extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.66.0/reference/destructors.html#extending-based-on-expressions)

See also:

([Code in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db535dd4b2a7f6f3b0ebc42b56c78563))