# Why partial move a struct in Rust will drop its unmoved field when the move and constructor occurs in same line?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, raii, drop

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: Bar,
}

impl Default for Foo{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Foo { a: "a".to_string(), b: Bar}
    }
}

struct Bar;

impl Drop for Bar {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("bar is dropped");
    }
}
```

Using the struct defined above, the `Bar` will be droped in different positions:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = Foo::default().a;
    // b:Bar is dropped here, as "bar is dropped" is printed before "start"
    println!("start");

}
```

When f is a reference to `a`, then `b` is only dropped at the end of `main()` scope.

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = &Foo::default().a; // add a & here
    
    println!("start");
    // b:Bar is dropped here, as "bar is dropped" is printed after "start"
}
```

So I assume the partial move one created a scope of only one line, so `b` is dropped early. Or `Foo::default()` can be replaced by `{Foo { a: "a".to_string(), b: Bar}}` literally, so the scope is one line?

But the reference one didn't create any scope, the compiler save the `Foo` instance to a invisible variable, so the scope ends at the main's end?

I don't know how to name this invisible variable scenario, so I can't search and get more information.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. It's called "Temporary Lifetime Extension". https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719720/5397009